# WebStorm vim tabn command

Tags: vim, webstorm

I am trying to map the `:tabn`/`:tabN` vim commands in WebStorm.

More specifically I would like to map this to `t`/`T` but I'm having trouble doing so.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Give description about what you did. Give the commands you tried. Explain more about what you want/

Comment: I have the ideavim plugin installed for Webstorm.  I'd like to be able to switch tabs (the Webstorm command is <Alt-Left/Right>) using a vim alias, t/T in command mode.  Is there a way to do this in the ideavimrc, or through the settings in webstorm?

Comment: You already have `gt` and `gT`, like in Vim.